# Why is $P(a < x < b) = P(a < x) - P(x < b)$?

Tags: probability-theory

Why is $P(a < x < b) = P(x < b) - P(x ≤ a)$?

This is an oversimplified version of a statistics problem I am doing, but I cannot remember why this is true. I know that this works and will give a correct solution, but what is the proof behind it?

Answer (score 5):

First, you probably need to switch around the probabilities on the right.  If $a<b$, then $P(x<a) \leq P(x<b)$, so the right-hand side of your expression could be negative.

It's probably more intuitive if you rewrite it as

$$ P(x < b) = P(x < a) + P(a<x<b)$$

Since $x<a$ is disjoint from $a<x<b$.

For this to work you need to have no finite mass at $x=a$; if not, the above equation can be adjusted to

$$ P(x < b) = P(x < a) + P(a \leq x<b)$$